# User event not firing on create event

Tags: netsuite

I'm having a strange problem, where a user event, made to fire for sales orders on the Create event type, is not starting at all for some of them.

Trigger on: BEFORE SUBMIT FUNCTION
STATUS - Released
EVENT TYPE - Create
LOG LEVEL- Error
EXECUTE AS ROLE - Full Access
All access boxes are checked.

The only pattern I've found so far is that all failures are being created by a Script (Scheduled), which makes little sense to me...

Has anyone found a similar issue??

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the scheduled script to trigger the user event script?  Do you have the "All Roles" checkbox checked? I believe you need this to be checked for the UE script to be execute when the scheduled script creates a record.

Comment: >Do you want the scheduled script to trigger the user event script?

Yes, the scheduled script creates a sales order, which should trigger the On Create event, 

>Do you have the "All Roles" checkbox checked?

Also yes, all boxes for employees, roles and subsidiaries are checked.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check your scheduled script if it is error free. One possible reason why the user event script is not running is because the scheduled script has an error. Run your scheduled script first from the script debugger to see if there are errors.

Comment: Hi, I've tried this and it runs OK on every other instance. Also tried runnning in on edit mode, and it does so I doubt is a code issue. I think it might be permission related because it runs on full access, and the triggering script runs on admin. I'm still waiting for test results.

Comment: All scheduled script runs on Admin role, so if your user event script is set to run on full access then that is the reason.

Comment: If there is an error in the script, you should get error message in Script deployment - Execution log ;)